# Update bower package configured by git url branch

Tags: gulp, bower, bower-install

I have a package in my bower.json file configured like this:

"package": "git@bitbucket.org:company/project.git#stage",

I own that package and update the stage's branch very often.

To update that bower component in the project which uses that library I have to reinstall the bower component removing the bower_components/package folder and reinstalling with bower install.

Is there any other way for bower to detect modifications in the stage's branch?

Answer (score 0):

Just running the install again (without the `--save` option) should work.

```
bower install https://bitbucket.org/company/project.git#stage
```

If not, first try to uninstall the package with:

```
bower uninstall https://bitbucket.org/company/project.git#stage
```

Comment: mm when I try those commands bower happens to dont recognize the package:
bower                     invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain minified files
bower                     invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain minified files
bower                        ENOTFOUND Package git not found

Comment: But if I remove the package from bower component and run a bower install it installs the package again

Comment: @lapinkoira the `main` field issue is a problem in your `bower.json` file. The `Package git not found` was caused by the wrong url format, I updated my answer with the valid URL.

Comment: git and https url works inside bower.json, if I remove the package manually rm -fr bower_components/package and then run bower install it works, but bower install git_url or bower install https_url doesnt work directly, with the last one it says bower                     ENORESTARGET URL sources can't resolve targets

Comment: I dont know what bower does internally. When I run just "bower install" at the bower output it says resolve git@bitbucket.org:company/project.git#stage" but if I use the same git url manually it doesnt work

Comment: @lapinkoira I tested it with jQuery using the repo url and I had to use the https url.